# Is there any possibility an artifact is available in the browser view of a maven repo, but can't be fetched by mvn -U install?

Tags: maven

I want to use the artifact

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
<artifactId>izpack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>5.0.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

as plugin which I can see at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/codehaus/izpack/izpack-maven-plugin/5.0.11-SNAPSHOT/. However specifying

```
<repository>
    <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
    <name>Sonatype Nexus snapshot repository</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
</repository>
```

right under `project.repositories` still causes `mvn -U clean install` to fails due to `[ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.izpack:izpack-maven-plugin:5.0.11-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.izpack:izpack-maven-plugin:jar:5.0.11-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]`. Does that make any sense given the fact that there's no error indicating failure in transmission, but only that the artifact can't be found?

I'm using Maven 3.3.9 on Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Are you sure the `sonatype-nexus-snapshots` repository is taken into account? (Is in an active profile, or other?)

Comment: It's right under `project.repositories`. There's a parent, but that shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. It should be under `<pluginRepositories>` if this is indeed a plugin. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203009/repository-for-maven-plugin-dependency-defined-in-pom-is-not-used

Comment: Better to mark as duplicate so that people are redirected to the correct answer.